# How Make a php array and insert it to db from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have need to upload data from csv.my current code upload data correctly .But I have need to separate my some column data those are repeated

Suppose

My csv column

```
company | area  |red show type | red show name | red show price | green show type | green show name | green show price |
```

i want to this data in different table

```
one table have company | area  | these two data
```

another table design is:

```
id|show_type|show_name|show_price
```

in my csv

```
red show type | red show name | red show price | green show type | green show name | green show price |
```

these column contain same type of data for two type of show red and green

now how can i insert data into database from csv

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) php method using the "|" as the delimeter.

After that you should be sorting the code using ifs and elses